# Is there a pattern for deserialization involving repository access? Or what is wrong with my design?

Tags: domain-driven-design, scala, serialization

Let us have

```
case class Money(amount: BigDecimal, currency: Currency)
case class Currency(code: String, alpha3: String)
```

`Money` is a value object and `Currency` is an entity. 
When transforming `Money` to JSON I would replace currency with its code. However reverse operation requires repository access (which is implemented using `Future`). Is there something wrong with my design? Should I introduce `CurrencyCode` value-object?

Comment: Why is `Currency` an entity? This means that if you manage to create two `Currency` instances for US Dollars, they must compare as different currencies, which is counter-intuitive.

Comment: I agree. And now I see that my Currency is actually a CurrencyInfo which is used mostly for display purpose. While the real domain Currency is just a wrapper for code.